# Show config of running UWSGI instance

Tags: uwsgi

I have an instance of UWSGI that is getting it's config from an INI file.  Everything seems fine, except it does not seem to be accepting the buffer-size config option properly.  I have it set to 65535, but I'm getting error messages in my logs like this:

> invalid uwsgi request (current strsize: 41260). skip.

It appears to me that it's skipping requests that are below the buffer size limit.

Is there a way to dump the options that a running instance is using so that I can verify it's buffer-size?